# Android data is not inserted in database in first time running

Tags: android, sqlite

I am going to create an application that allow we get all songs on SD card, then push list of songs to SQLite on a service. The next, I want to get all song on activity and display progress dialog.
I got a problem when running: On the first time, it displays nothing (just display the progress dialog forever). But when I run it again (second time), it runs well.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mListSongs = new ArrayList<>();
    lvSong = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_song);
    Intent it = new Intent(this, ScanSongService.class);
    startService(it);
    mDbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    mListSize = mDbHelper.getDBSize();
    Log.d(TAG, "-------- mListSize on activity: " + mListSize);
    new ScanSongAsyncTask(this).execute();
}
```

Example from above code: 
On the service, I loaded all song and add to DB. I have logged, it's fine.
In the first time, **mListSize** is 0. 
In the second time, **mListSize** is 12 ( number of songs on sd card).

Comment: where you add data into database?

Comment: when you start service `startService(it);` it will take time before it complete it's work, so calling `mDbHelper = new DBHelper(this);` will not fetch correct (or any) data cuz service still running or even insert not started yet. you will need to trigger something from the service when the job is completed.

Comment: @ExceptionLover: As i said on the topic, I load all the song (.mp3) from sd card

Comment: @Yazan: Thank you, your answer is same to Akram Shokri answer. Maybe I create a button for handling event

Comment: i don't think a button is the best answer, you have to implement a mechanism that will allow the service to notify the activity when scan and db-insert is complete, so the activity can load data into the list, have a look at sending a broadcast  in general and **how to send broadcast from service to activity** this way it will be automated and on time :)

Comment: @Yazan thanks, you are right

Answer (score 0):

It is because you inserted the data in the service and it takes time to service (which is running on a separate thread) do its work but you instantly get the size of the inserted data (just after you started the service).
You should get the size in your service after it finishes the insertion.

Alternatively you can use an AsyncTask and do the insertion in its `doInBackgroung` method and then get the size (or do any post-processing you want) in its `onPostExecute` method. The problem you mentioned you had with progress bar can be solved by using AsyncTask too (just dismiss the progress bar in `onPostExecute` method).

In case of using service as you did here, change your code for inserting data as below:

```
void insertData (){
  //your code for inserting data
  .... 
   Log.d(TAG, "-------- mListSize on activity: " + mListSize);
   new ScanSongAsyncTask(this).execute(); 
}
```

i.e. move the start of your `ScanSongAsyncTask` and the logging of the Db size after data insertion codes.
If you need to update UI like updating listView, use `runOnUIThread` to do it.

Comment: @Akaram Shokri: Thank for your answer, but that is my task. I have to insert data on service. If I do all works on activity, it's no problem, sir :)

Comment: @Brascelok Wel, I suggested using AsyncTask and by using it you still avoided doing al work in the activity. Also, you can use AsyncTask in your service too, although it is not a good approach for your case. However, if you have to use service, you can and you in fact did it.  I have updated my answer to show how to do it in service.

Comment: Is the insertData () method on Service right ? I have read some tuts that recommend we should not call async task on service, as you said. I will try with new solution, that is creating new button on activity and then handle the async task on button event